# How to install npm -g on offline server

Tags: node.js, offline, npm

I need to install a "global" npm applications on an offline server.

It is easy to install a normal application:

```
npm install
```

and then pack up the resulting files. Either manually or using *npm pack*.

However, how can I install global application (that has a install script of some sort) such as *forever* without Internet?

```
npm install -g forever
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox), it is the new name of npmzip which will allow you to install offline npm packages by one file

Comment: I installed npmbox pn the server but how to install pm2 using that?

Comment: Sorry but didn't work for me. Spent quite a bit of time trying until desisted. Did find how and posted below.

Comment: npmbox is a dead project. Don't bother.

Comment: my question how to install npmbox without internet access?

Comment: npmbox does not work anymore.

Answer (score 19):

You can install stuff from a tarball file, check out the [npm documentation](http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html). You can find the URL of the forever tarball with `npm view forever dist.tarball` and download that. Try something like this:

```
curl -so forever.tar.gz `npm view forever dist.tarball 2> /dev/null`
npm install ./forever.tar.gz -g
```

But you might have to do this for all of the dependencies as well. There might be a better way but this is what I've found in my search.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it immediately tries to pull in the dependencies from Internet. *npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway*

Comment: Naturally, you would need to install any dependencies first.

Comment: You are correct Kato. But how? There are a lot of dependencies for **forever**.

Answer (score 8):

Well.... after a day trying to make it work with above references (npmbox or offline-npm) came up with something way much simpler. Thanks to npmbox I have to say.
The idea is the keep the cache from the instance that has online access and then use it in the one offline.

**In machine with internet:**

1 - clear npm cache: `npm cache clear`

2 - install package, lets say its x.y.z: `npm install -g **package.x.y.z**`

3 - copy cache in to a folder... let's call it whatever (I assume npm cache is in root folder, not absolutely sure about that):
 `cp -R /.npm/* **/cache-whatever-folder**`

**In machine with no internet:**

4 - take this cache-whatever-folder to the instance with no internet and after that, clean cache and install with it (I won't indicate how to copy the folder :)

`npm cache clear`

`npm install --global --cache **/cache-whatever-folder** --optional --cache-min 99999999999 --shrinkwrap false **package.x.y.z**`

Done

Comment: npm-cache makes no guarantees that the cache will be complete or not corrupted. How this could happen could be due to auto cache cleanup, or hash collisions. The npm-cache docs say this "npm makes *no guarantee* that a previously-cached piece of data will be available later"

Comment: do i just copy the npm-cache folder and  replace in other machine? I am using windows not sure how u used the cp command. If you could elaborate the file path it would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, @MurtazaHaji, get the data from `%AppData%/npm-cache` in the machine with internet access and copy it to the one the hasn't.

Answer (score 6):

**INSTALL PM2 OFFLINE:-**

> Tested on Node-v6.10.3 and Npm-3.10.10 on RHEL-7

**Go to machine with internet connection:-**

```
#npm install -g npmbox
#npmbox npmbox
#scp npmbox.npmbox root@offline-server-ip:.
```

**Go to machine without internet connection :-**

```
#ssh  root@offline-server-ip 
#tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions -xvzf npmbox.npmbox
#npm install --global --cache ./.npmbox.cache --optional --cache-min 99999999999 --shrinkwrap false npmbox
```

**Go to machine with internet connection:-**

```
#npm install pm2 -g
#npmbox pm2
#scp pm2.npmbox root@offline-server-ip:.
```

**Go to machine without internet connection :-**

```
#npmunbox pm2.npmbox --global
#pm2 ls
```

Answer (score 4):

I created [offline-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm) for getting all the dependencies installed in a clean way. For modules without the use of node-gyp everything should work as described.

If you require `node-gyp` (which is usually installed online) consider copying ~/.node-gyp to that offline machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try [npmzip](https://npmjs.org/package/npmzip)

```
npm install -g npmzip
npmzip <package>
```

You will get the tarball in the current directory
This may be moved to the target machine and :

```
npmunzip <tarball>
```

Comment: npm can handel tar.gz zip git svn by default
[manual](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#dependencies)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/):

1. On the internet machine (configure local cache location):

   ```
   yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ~/yarn-offline-mirror/
   ```
2. On the offline machine (configure local cache location):

   ```
   yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ~/yarn-offline-mirror/
   ```
3. On the offline machine, Find out where is the global installation location:

   ```
   yarn global bin
   ```

   (Or set it with `yarn config set prefix <file_path>`)
4. On the offline machine, add it to your path. E.g.:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:'"$(yarn global bin)" >> ~/.bashrc  
   source ~/.bashrc # reload
   ```
5. On the internet machine, download `forever`'s dependencies:

   ```
   mkdir new-cli-forever/
   cd new-cli-forever/
   yarn add forever
   ```

   Then copy `new-cli-forever/yarn.lock` and `~/yarn-offline-mirror/` to the offline machine. (`rm -rf new-cli-forever/` is ok now.)
6. On the offline machine, install `forever` from local cache:

   ```
   cp /path/to/imported/yarn.lock .
   cp -n /path/to/imported/yarn-offline-mirror/* ~/yarn-offline-mirror/
   yarn global add --offline forever
   rm -f ./yarn.lock
   ```

For more info, see my post here: https://assafmo.github.io/2018/04/11/yarn-offline.html

Comment: How do you get yarn to the offline machine in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the only solution of this thread that worked for me. My only remark is that in my case, I had to run yarn --offline to create the project before yarn global add --offline dep. Otherwise, it did not work

Comment: Oh, and also, you can force engine versions with this option : --ignore-engines. For instance, yarn add --ignore-engines dep
In my case, this came helpful to install pm2

Comment: Umm. How to get `yarn` on the offline server?

Answer (score 2):

List the dependencies in `bundledDependencies` in your package.json, and then run `npm pack` to create a tarball. Get that over to the other machine, and either `npm install <tarball>`, or just crack it open manually.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1349

Answer (score 2):

> ## npmbox is outdated

Use `npm pack` command ([npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack.html)), no need to install anything.

#### Single package

If you want only one package (for example, `forever`), you can run:

```sh
npm pack forever
```

> this command will fetch it to the cache, and then copy the tarball to the current working directory as -.tgz

Then, from the folder you created the package, you install it with:

```sh
npm install -g ./forever-x.y.z.tgz
```

---

#### Whole project

If you want a whole project to be installed offline, include a poperty in your `package.json` named `bundleDependencies` and list all dependecies you need in this field.

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
  "archiver": "^2.1.1",
  "axios": "^0.16.2",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.3"
},
"bundleDependencies": {
  "archiver": "^2.1.1",
  "axios": "^0.16.2",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.3"
}
```

Then run `npm pack`.

It will create a `.tgz` file of your whole project and dependencias.

You just have to copy it to the offline server and untar.

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine or any machine that has internet connection, do

```
npm install npm-bundle -g
npm install forever -g
```

Now, go to `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever` and do

```
npm-bundle
```

It will create a `.tgz` file. Now `scp/ftp` that `.tgz` file to the offline server and do

```
npm install forever -g
```

Reference: [This blog](https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/02/node-js-packaging-modules-for-offline-deployment-using-npm-bundle/)

Comment: Followed all steps , still npm install timesout because its trying to connect to registry.npmjs.org which isnt allowed in my production machine

Answer (score 0):

On an online machine do:

```sh
# change to desired packages
packages="pm2 yarn"
for pkg in $packages; do
    mkdir "$pkg"
    curl "$(npm view "$pkg" dist.tarball)" |
    tar -xzC "$pkg" --strip-components 1
    (cd "$pkg" && npm install)
done
tar -czf packages.tar.gz $packages
```

On the offline server do:

```
npm config set offline
tar -xzf packages.tar.gz
npm install -g pm2 yarn
```