# npm install "karma-0.10.4.tgz" fails on a computer without an internet connection

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

I'm trying to install karma with npm on a computer not connected to the internet.

On a connected computer I executed "npm pack karma", took the tgz file and tried to run "npm install karma-0.10.4.tgz" but got this error:

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you add a relative path: `npm install ./karma-0.10.4.tgz`?

Comment: It might be trying to installing a dependency. Have you seen npmbox as mentioned in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server ?

Comment: npmbox looks good, but then I figured - "how do you install npmbox" on an offline machine? :) anyway, eventually I just copied my connected machine's npm folder to the offline machine and that's it. Probably not the best solution, but works perfectly for me.