# Offline Node.JS Packages

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, offline, package-managers, phantomcss

How do I install node packages on an offline machine?

For instance, I am trying to install PhantomCSS onto a machine with no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an automated package boxing tool like [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox) is preferred, because even though it can be done with npm alone, all dependencies must be carefully downloaded and installed. npmbox does the hard work for you. Perform `npmbox phantomcss` on a computer with an internet connection, take the resulting package to your offline computer via another means (such as a pen drive), then install the package with `npmunbox phantomcss.npmbox`.

---

Here is the alternative that I wrote before. I had chosen to follow [this piece of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295323/1233251) for the answer.

Running `npm view phantomcss` will give you something like this at the end of the output:

```
dist:
{ shasum: '5a6cacc60934daed76031cf372a76aff240ba117',
 tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/phantomcss/-/phantomcss-0.9.1.tgz' },
directories: {} }
```

Download the tarball on a computer with an internet connection. Transfer it to your offline computer, then install the package with `npm install`:

```
npm install /directory/to/your/package/phantomcss-0.9.1.tgz
```

Just appending what the other answer mentions: all other dependencies must be installed manually before doing this.

Comment: awesome thanks! any idea how to untar the npmbox.npmbox file? Is there something else I need to install in order to be able to run the tar command?

Comment: Well yes! Install npmbox on both computers (npmunbox will be included). The package installation is already provided in the answer.

Comment: Thanks this was perfect! I'm trying to automate now and when running npmunbox from powershell or a batch it keeps trying to look online. Works fine if I type it in manually. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: npmunbox phantomcss works fine when typed in manually. If I run a powershell or batch script with the same command it will run but tries to search online for the package (tries to hit bitbucket instead of just grabbing the .npmbox file)