# What exact command is to install pm2 on offline RHEL

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, redhat, pm2

First of all it's not a duplicate question of below:-

[How to install npm -g on offline server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976100/how-to-installl-pm2-on-offline-server

I install npmbox (https://github.com/arei/npmbox) on my offline REHL server but I'm still do not know how to install pm2 or any other package using that.

Please advise.

Comment: @downvoter: kindly leave a solution if you know?

Comment: @Soren: How to include all dependencies in the pack?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You use npm install & pack

First on a machine that is online you install

```
$ npm install pm2
```

Then you pack it up

```
$ npm pack pm2
```

That gives you a tar file -- you copy that tar file to your offline machine and install, like

```
$ npm install pm2-2.2.1.tgz
```

The above however only create a tarball for the specific module expluding dependencies, and you may still have dependencies that you need to resolve. While you could simply walk through and pack every dependency manually, there is a modules that will automated that for you

```
$ npm install -g npm-bundle
```

Then you can do

```
$ npm-bundle pm2
```

for the individual packages, or if you have a `package.json` for your project

```
$ npm-bundle
```

to pack everything in one big tarball

Comment: thanks a lot. npm install pm2-2.2.1.tgz -g worked for me.

Comment: how to include all dependencies in the package?

Comment: http://fabianlee.org/2016/10/02/node-js-packaging-modules-for-offline-deployment-using-npm-bundle/ I tried this but it is also not working. it's looking for https://registry.npmjs.org/pm2/-/pm2-2.2.2.tgz

Comment: npm-bundle works perfectly for me .. did you try to install pm2 locally (without -g) before bundle ... added my steps above

Comment: and ```npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to install pm2 offline is:

Create the tar file with the above steps mentioned by @soren.

in my case Installation hung while executing "npm install pm2.tar.gz".

```
npm install pm2.tar.gz

[..................] - fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule pm2@5.1.2 checking installable status
[..................] - fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule pm2@5.1.2 checking installable status
```

to get this resolved I have added the npm registry but that **did not work.**

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

Server's are into the DMZ or in a private subnet that's it's was not working.

**Solution:-**

Get the install path of the node_module directory

```
#npm config get prefix
```

Extract the tar file & Copy the pm2 directory to node_module

```
 #tar -zxvf pm2.tar.gz
 #cp pm2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ -r
```

cd into the /usr/bin & Crete the simlink for pm2

```
 # cd /usr/bin
 #ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 pm2
```

check pm2 command output & its output.

```
    # pm2
    usage: pm2 [options] <command>

    pm2 -h, --help             all available commands and options
    pm2 examples               display pm2 usage examples
    pm2 <command> -h           help on a specific command

    Access pm2 files in ~/.pm2
```

Answer (score 1):

- On a linux machine with internet access:

  - `cd /home/myName/Downloads`
  - `rm -r *` (clear contents of folder)
  - `npm i -g npm-bundle` (globally install this package if you do not have it already)
  - `npm i pm2` (will create node_modules, package.json, and package-lock.json)
  - `npm-bundle pm2` (this will create a .tgz file)
- Move the `.tgz` file to the offline machine, untar it (`tar -xvzf pm2-#.#.#.tgz`, rename its folder to `pm2` (`mv package pm2`)
- `npm root -g` (will show you where to put files for global packages)
- `cp -r pm2 /usr/lib/node_modules/`
- `ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 /usr/local/bin/pm2` (create symlink for the pm2 command)
- `pm2 ls` (should work now)

Answer (score 0):

@Soren's answer work for me. to install it globally you need to pass -g argument to it.

Tested it on OpenSUSE 15 Enterprise.

for example:

```
ip-192-168-2-36:~ # npm install pm2-5.1.2.tgz -g
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 181 packages, and audited 182 packages in 5s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


ip-192-168-2-36:~ # pm2 -v
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
5.1.2
```

Without -g argument pm2 command will not work.

```
ip-192-168-2-36:~ # pm2
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pm2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way,

just write a node service on your machine pm2 no longer needed to run you application.

### Step -1

Run the command to find the node path
which node --> /opt/rh/rh-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node

### Step -2

cd /etc/systemd/system

### Step -3

Write a service of node as follows :-

```
vi node.service

[Unit]
Description=Node Service for Dashboard Application
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node 
/home/node/deployed/backend/server.js SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

:wq!
```

--> save it

### Step -4

Start the node service

```
systemctl start node.service
```

### Step -5

```
systemctl status node.service
```

### Step -6

Check your application your node is running without pm2