# How to dowload node.js and install it on diffrent machine

Tags: node.js

I need to install Node.js on machine without Internet access. I want to do that by downloading node.js package, move it to machine without Internet access and then install it on that machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can scp that package from machine to other machine but they both should be in same network **no internet required just connection will work**.Than follow procedure of installing node via that module.

Comment: Do you need the `node.exe` binary or do you want to install `npm` packages?

Comment: Sounds like a virtual machine environment would be the best bet, then you can simply copy over the VM image (still... you'd need to have the virtualization software installed too). Maybe Docker could even work, but I'm not familiar with the possibility to manually install docker images. I guess it should be possible.

Comment: Which OS are we talking about?

Comment: I want to do that on Red Hat. I need node.js and then install some npm package. For npm I will use solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server