# How to run the Dist Folder on Local Machine in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am building the application in `Angular6+`, now I ran the command `ng build --prod` which gave me a dist folder. How do I check or serve that folder on Localhost?

Comment: Generally, you can install locally any HTTP server which will serve your project distribution files, for example [XAMP, npm package "http-server", ....]

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can do that using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package.

First install the package **globally**

`npm install http-server -g`

Then inside your project directory(in the terminal) just run

> `http-server dist/`

And if you are using Angular 6+ or above (**Working with Angular 10**), You have to run

> `http-server dist/your-project-name`

Now you can visit http://localhost:8080 to view your application

Comment: Let me try & check in a moment

Comment: If you have `npm` > 5.2 installed then you can do the same as above without the global install by using `npx`. E.g. `npx http-server dist/`. That will download and run the binary each time you execute, so for a once off or infrequent usage it's pretty good. Should you use the package a lot or need if offline then follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: This error is coming when i run http-serve dist/project-name 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: did you install the package **globally**?

Comment: Thanks Brother. It worked I installed it again & now all works fine.

Comment: in a local machine without internet how to perform " npm install http-server -g "

Comment: @Sajith read this. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server]

Comment: it does not work when i reload the browser after navigating to a route. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I am using angular 7.x.x in my application, when i am trying to run in 192.168.2.36:8080 or localhost:8080 ports Application is not running. and it is showing 'This page is not working..'. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. thanks in advance

Comment: Same problem of @Santhosh, http-server gives a series of addresses where to find the app but none of them work...

Comment: @Santhosh I'll look in to this and update you. I haven't tried this with angular 7.

Comment: can we use this `http-server` on production server? or is there any other (proper) way?

Comment: @FranklinPious **For fixing the issue on reloading after navigation**  you can either 1) duplicate your `index.html` and rename it as `404`.html. 2) run `http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080?`, which proxies all requests which can't be resolved locally to the given URL. For further explanations check this thread https://github.com/http-party/http-server/pull/369

Answer (score 27):

Edit: Angular 12+: `ng serve --configuration production`

Since Angular 7 you can just do `ng serve --prod=true`. Documentation: https://angular.io/cli/serve

I know the question asks about Angular 6 but Google got me here, so just for future reference.

Answer (score 18):

In my case I did next:

Install **http-server** globally

`npm install http-server -g`

Then inside the project directory (in the terminal), I run

`http-server dist/[your-project-name]`

Now you can visit http://localhost:8080/index.html to view your application.
But when I restart the browser page I have to add again /index.html into URL.

---

It works in **Angular 7.x.x** version.

Answer (score 7):

**From Terminal:** 
$ npm install http-server -g

From Angular Project Dir. Lets say your Angular project name is ngx. 
$ ng build 
$ http-server dist/ngx 
Starting up http-server, serving dist/ngx 
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:8080 
http://192.168.43.54:8080 
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 2):

windows platform

```
 - Install wamp server --> 
   https://wampserver.en.softonic.com/ and start.
 - your dist folder files copy to c:/wamp/www/(your project name)/
 - And create .htaccess file redirect your index.html.
   (http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-faq/)
 - Next run browser http://localhost/(your project name)
```

ubuntu platform

```
 - Install lamp server --> 
   https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/ and start.
 - your dist folder files copy to /opt/lampp/htdocs/(your project name)/
 - And create .htaccess file redirect your index.html.
   (http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-faq/)
 - Next run browser http://localhost/(your project name)
```