# In angular 7 , On running the dist on local machine , when on reloading or rehitting the url, the page throwing the error

Tags: angular

In angular 7, On running the dist on local machine , for the first time web page is  loading. And when on reloading or hit the url, the page throwing the error.

I am used this link to run on the local machine

[How to run the Dist Folder on Local Machine in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129053/how-to-run-the-dist-folder-on-local-machine-in-angular-6)

On Reload and for hit the url I am using .htaccess file. but Its not work.

- I took the template build  with command 
  ng build --prod
- I changed in index.html
   href="/browser/"
- For run on the local machine I am used http-server.

  First install the package globally using command

  npm install http-server -g.

  Then inside the project directory(in the terminal) just run

  ```
  http-server dist/.
  ```

For the first time web page is  loading on the local machine and when on reloading or hit the url, the page throwing the server error.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: http-server does not support `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Thanks , but how its possible for reloading the url on http-server.

Answer (score 0):

Put below line in angular.json file, then try.

```
"deployUrl": "dist/",
```

Above line put like this.

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "public/dist",
        "deployUrl": "dist/",
```

Thanks