# Angular: Loading Site Results in Redirect Error

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-build

I've built my Angular project and sent dist folder to another computer. Then I've tried to run it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129182/4116960).
I've got this:
[image]
but when going to the addresses specified or localhost it gives invalid redirect error and no page is loaded.

**UPDATE**

index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <base href='/'>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/img/apple-icon.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/img/favicon.png" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title></title>

  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="loader">
      <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I simply do `ng build` and then the instructions provided in the linked answer above.

**Edit**
I've tried setting

```
<base href='./heliosFrontEnd_admin/dist'>
```

in index.html of dist but didn' work.

Comment: Can you share your command for building application and please provide `<base href=>` in your `index.html`?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question

Comment: Have u tried `<base href='./'>` ?

Comment: @PareshLomate Yes I've tried that also :\

Comment: Can you provide the error from the developers console log?

Comment: Hi @HenslerSoftware, in the console there is no error shown (actually nothing written). The page doesn't load at all ... While in the command line everytime I refresh the page and try to load it I have this `[Wed May 22 2019 09:56:03 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0" ` so apparently it recognize something is performing a GET