# how to run the index.html file after ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I have created a new angular app using this command:

```
ng new angularapp
```

after that, I have used this command to generate a dist folder.

```
ng build --prod
```

after that, I tried to open the index.html file in dist folder but I am getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1FIa.png)

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129053/how-to-run-the-dist-folder-on-local-machine-in-angular-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a running http server to view the application once it's build

If you  just wan't to view the application in your local browser  you could run a  server  using tools like VS code extention [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

You could also install run and run  local apache server and place the files in the root folder and visit localhost using tools like Wamp , Xamp or Lamp.

OR

You can do that using `http-server` npm package.

Step 1 : First install the package globally

`npm install http-server -g`.

Step 2 :Then inside your project directory(in the terminal) just run

```
http-server dist/.
```

And if your are using angular 6.x.x, You have to run

```
http-server dist/your-project-name
```

Now you can visit http://localhost:8080 to view your application