# Error deploying Angular project on heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have deployed my Angular project to heroku. It's showing error as not found. I tried running the same project in node server.js the same error some files not found.
I tried this https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147 .
But I think there's some error in the server.js file.
Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const server = require('http').Server(app);


// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/RouterApp'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/RouterApp/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port


server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})
```

When I tried putting the path as `/src/index.html`, the index page is loading but not the Angular components.
This is my directory structure

```
>>RouterApp
  >>...
  >>server.js
  >>src
    >>index.html
    >>components
  >>...
```

Error I'm getting while running using `node server.js`
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/RouterApp/RouterApp/index.html'

When I try running the program on `localhost:4200` it runs perfectly fine using `ng serve`.
Here's the GitHub repo https://github.com/Pradeep2898/QuoraClone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I get the issue. My project was not creating the dist folder on deployment. I tried this steps

```
cd RouterApp
ng build  //this will creat a dist folder
// now run the node server.js
node server.js
>>App running on port 4200
// Open the app locally on port 4200, https: localhost:4200
// It will work. Push the changes to git repository.
// It worked.
```

https://quora-ui-clone.herokuapp.com/

Try installing npm install http-server -g
Then run `http-server/dist`

[How to run the Dist Folder on Local Machine in Angular 6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129053/how-to-run-the-dist-folder-on-local-machine-in-angular-6)