# is it possible to run vue production build locally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apache, xampp

I created a dist folder using `npm run build` command in my vue project. I put the dist folder at C:\xampp\htdocs\ and then I started the apache server to test the app locally. whenever I type the `http://localhost/dist/index.html` in my browser, there is only a blank white page.
so, is it possible to run production build locally?

Comment: This should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129182/2627160

Comment: Yeah, no need for a XAMPP server here.

Comment: whenever I run `http-server dist/` it shows this error: http-server : File C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: You pretty much have your answer, you need to get more privileges: follow the link.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably have something like this in your `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "preview": "vite preview",
},
```

supposing you're using Vue3.

Otherwise, [serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve#readme) is a nice alternative to preview an SPA, no need for a XAMPP server. You can install that globally so that you have it on your whole computer.

If you don't have Vite (like in a Vue2 project) or if you want to quickly preview a static app, the command to run is like this

```
serve dist
```

PS: you may also need to get admin rights if you're in Windows.